# carousel img background is not cover on iphone

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, background-image, carousel

I have use background-image in item carousel. Background property are: cover center and fixed. It work on desktop but not on iphone (yes on android). On this device the device is not adapted to the screen, and show only a very litter part of image and i don't no why....

```
.carousel-inner .item
{
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    -webkit-background-position: center;
    -moz-background-position: center;
    -o-background-position: center;
    background-position: center;

    -webkit-background-attachment: fixed;
    -moz-background-attachment: fixed;
    -o-background-attachment: fixed;
    background-attachment: fixed;

    }
```

html:

```
<div class="item slideimg3">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>Lorem ipsus</h1>
        <p>Etiam tellus felis, fringilla vitae dictum id, dapibus id est.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: On this device the device is not adapted to the screen? I don't understand. The issue on iOs only on safari? Chrome?

Comment: @german the problem was only on IOS. i have solved by media replacing backgroun-attachment: scroll and backgound-size 100% in all media apple device